# X-GNOME-Autostart=false but process is still run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, unix, gnome-keyring

As I understand adding `X-GNOME-Autostart=false` at the end of a file in `~/.config/autostart/...` should prevent an application from starting it at autostart. I'm adding this line at the end of `gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` file but `gnome-keyring` process is still run.

It is clearly some changes after setting this.I create a UNIX socket and set SSH_AUTH_SOCK before creating a session, and now `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` contains the path to my UNIX socket(before setting `X-GNOME...` some process was overwriting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and it had some other value).

---

### Question

What exactly does this `X-GNOME-Autostart=false` do?

I'm using ubuntu 14.

Answer (score -1):

That's not the same process.

During startup, `gnome-keyring-daemon` runs several times:

1. PAM (pam_gnome_keyring) launches the main `gnome-keyring-daemon` process, which loads the keyring and unlocks it based on your login password.
2. GNOME launches `gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11`, which just tells the *main* process to initialize its PKCS#11 (certificate) module.
3. GNOME launches `gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh`, which just tells the *main* process to initialize its SSH module.

Disabling items #2 and #3 won't prevent PAM from doing its job.

Comment: So you mean that `gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh/pkcs11` won't be launched?

Comment: The questions was, `What exactly does this X-GNOME-Autostart=false do?` and this answer completely fails to answer that.